# Sending XML data from computer to computer - Qt

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have no experience in this topic so I have to ask.
How to send (XML formatted) data from one computer to another using Qt Framework ?

Edit :

I found out that sockets are suitable for this, but I have no idea how to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file transfer with **Qt** you'll use `QTcpServer` and `QTcpSocket`. You can check out some [Network Examples](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/examples-network.html) on their website.